# I need to show that the following function is positive.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need to show  that the following function is positive.
$H(x)=2(7)^x+2(4)^x-2(3)^x+2(d+1)^x+2((d-2)(d+4))^x-2(d+2)^x-2((d-1)(d+5))^x$

Where $d=3,4,5 $  and $x\in[-1,0)$

From graph for different values of $d$ I found that it is increasing function and initial value is also positive.

**I want some proof doing some calculation without the use of graph. Can you help me to prove in some different method without using the graph.**

Thanks

Comment: hint: $a^x>0 \forall x$

Comment: This is going to be tricky, because these functions are not globally monotonic and their roots (and the roots of their derivatives) do not have an elementary form. Perhaps you can use Taylor's theorem with remainder to get an estimate of $H$ that provably bounds it away from zero.

Comment: By the way, where does this problem come from? Do you expect a nice solution (i.e. the question comes from an exercise)?

Answer (score 1):

The following approach is **ugly** but will get you what you want, with enough work. Hopefully somebody else will come along and find a more clever solution.

Let's look at the $d=3$ case. We can ignore the factor of $2$, which leaves us with
$$H(x) = 7^x + 4^x - 3^x + 4^x + 7^x - 5^x - 16^x$$
By Taylor's theorem we have that
$$H(-1+x) = T^n(x) + R^n(x),$$
where
$$T^n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}H^{(i)}(-1)$$
is the degree $n$ Taylor polynomial and $R^n(x)$ is the remainder term.

Let $K(x) = - 3^x - 5^x - 16^x$.
Notice that $H^{(n)}(x) \geq K^{(n)}(x)$ for all $n$ and $x\in (-1,0)$, and that $K$ is monotonic decreasing, so
$$R^{(n)}(x) \geq \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}K^{(n+1)}(0)$$
on $(0,1)$. So $H$ is positive on $[-1,0)$ if, for some $n$, the polynomial
$$T^n(x) + \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}K^{(n+1)}(0)$$
has no roots in $(0,1)$. Trial and error shows that this is true for $n=5$:

[image]

Lack of a root can be proven formally using e.g. Sturm's theorem.